# Firebase: Allow deleting user content after delete account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to delete user's content in firestore after they delete their account from my app. Without rules this seemed to work, but with rules I am getting permission errors. I am assuming this is because the user is already deleted and is not allowed to delete content anymore.

---

Code:

```
this.currentUser.delete().then( () => {
  //delete content from firestore
});
```

Rules:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

---

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Things I have considered:

- Deleting content before deleting account, but I think this will be problematic  if deleting the account would fail for some reason.
- `allow delete: if request.auth.uid != null` but wouldn't this mean that any user could delete anyone's content?
- Using a cloud function trigger. This would be an option, but I wonder if I can avoid this.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using Cloud Functions?  This is, by far, the best solution.

Comment: @DougStevenson - Good point. Not really trying to avoid, but was just wondering if I could keep my existing solution when I did not have rules set up yet. But I think I will move on to this approach indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `currentUser.delete()` method is something your script/logic calls (not the end user). So, if you want to offer a "delete account" button that's fine but have it's click listener fire a function called, ...i dunno, `deleteUserData(uid).then` before performing the `currentUser.delete()` method.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are suggesting something similar to my first point in "things i have considered" from my original post. I was just thinking it makes more sense to make sure to delete the user's account first (in case this results in an error), and then continue to deleting the user's content. Or am I overthinking this here?